# Synthesize speech on Windows 10: 'Scenario_SynthesizeText.g.h' file not found

Tags: c++, uwp, window

I have some experience with JS, Python, Go, but for the first time I need to accomplish something with C++. I can try to get synthesized audio with C# but I think it is better to absorb knowledge about more generic technology. I follow [this documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.speechsynthesis.speechsynthesizer). From [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis/cpp/Scenario_SynthesizeText.xaml.cpp) I found that I need to include `Scenario_SynthesizeText.xaml.h`.

In my official Windows 10 Virtualbox image I installed Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 plus Universal Windows Platform build tools.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Scenario_SynthesizeText.xaml.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";

    InitializeComponent();
    synth = std::ref new SpeechSynthesizer();
    media = std::ref new MediaElement();

    return 0;
}
```

But compilation is failed on Windows 10:

```
D:\>cl __windowsTTSTest.cc

fatal error: 'Scenario_SynthesizeText.g.h' file not found
```

Looks like I need to install some dependency? No such file in Google...

Comment: You are taking code from a GUI app and pasting it into a console app, but you didn't copy the GUI infrastructure the code relies on. Scenario_SynthesizeText.g.h is created by the XAML compiler when you compile Scenario_SynthesizeText.xaml. Note also that the code you're copying is written in the C++/CX language, not pure C++. You'll have to add C++/CX support to your compiler command line. I would suggest starting with the app as-is to learn how the classes work, and then writing a new console app based on what you learned, rather than by trying to force GUI code to work outside of a GUI.

Comment: @RaymondChen thank you for help. Can I drop that `xaml` dependency? How can I import `SpeechSynthesizer` for my cli app from some Windows SDK?

Comment: You can use C++/WinRT to access the SpeechSynthesizer directly. `winrt::Windows::Media::SpeechSynthesis::SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer; auto stream = co_await synthesizer.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(winrt::hstring(L"Hello"));` and then you can render the stream to your favorite media player.

Comment: @RaymondChen thank you for help again. For using `winrt` I need to import something?

Comment: There's an [entire section of documentation on using C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/). For this, it would be `#include <winrt/Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.h>`